# Backup the server

Tags: server, backup, schedule

I am using Ubuntu as a server with Windows XP clients. There are many files shared via [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29). I need to schedule automatic backup of the files which is shared via samba (that is i need to backup the samba share completely) and the files in apache svn which in my Ubuntu server to another computer. Which one is better to store backups, a Ubuntu PC or Windows PC?

Also, what are the procedures in setting up automatic backup?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; it reads like the objective is backing up the XP clients, not the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: @jackweirdy, no it's about backing up the Ubuntu machine.  The fact that it happens to be sharing files via samba is irrelevant.

Comment: @psusi I completely misread the question! My mistake

Comment: @jackweirdy the fact is i actually need to backup the folders which are under the smb share and also the files in apache svn. Plz help